# How to look up values from a different table?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have a log file of messages in one table in a MySQL database. Among some other stuff, it contains the sender id, and the message itself. I want to make a way to display the log on a website.

I have a separate table that contains the sender ids and the name of the person (which is what I actually want to display).

Are there any better ways than simply running another query? While that would work, that's pretty expensive as it requires a new query for every entry. Ideally, I'd like something that would map the id --> name in an array, but I can only find things that will put everything from one row into an array (aka, horizontally), but I need entries "vertically".

I'm using PHP by the way...

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about [`JOIN` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). This is exactly what you need.

Comment: Make sure you don't have ambiguous column names. use `tablename.columnname` syntax where needed.

Comment: I used: SELECT users.name, log.message, log.timestamp
FROM log, users
WHERE log.sender = users.id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Comment: -sigh- I'm guessing you don't bother enclosing your field names in `` ` backticks, since you're acting surprised that using a keyword for a name doesn't work.

Comment: In fact I did, and it did not work that way. So I took them out and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT `name`, `message` FROM `msgtable` INNER JOIN `sendertable` USING(`sender_id`)
```